# Ruby: Alias child to parent namespace so that classes can be instantiated using the parent namespace only

Tags: ruby

I would like to access child namespace classes using just the parent namespace as a prefix.

I want my models and controllers to live in separate child folders and for them to have a child namespace, but can then alias the child namespace so that it can be accessed via root namespace.

```
# This is the only class that is in the root namespace
provider = Cool::Provider.new

# Live in models namespace
company = Cool::Company.new
employee = Cool::Employee.new

# Live in controllers namespace
company_controller = Cool::CompanyController.new
employee_controller = Cool::EmployeeController.new
```

Thank you to those that have replied about mapping one class at a time to parent namespace, but I have seen a different mechanism that seemed more natural in a popular GEM and I am trying to find that technique.

I was looking at a popular gem a few months ago (forgotten which gem) and they added some code at the bottom of each child namespace to make that class available as if it was in the parent namespace, but I cannot locate that gem or how they did it.

Let's say I have a list of classes in these files

```
cool/provider.rb
cool/models/company.rb
cool/models/employee.rb
cool/controllers/company_controller.rb
cool/controllers/employee_controller.rb
```

Here are the classes

```
module Cool
  class Provider
  end
end

module Cool
  module Model
    class Company
    end
  end
  # The GEM I saw, did something here
end

module Cool
  module Model
    class Employee
    end
  end 
  # The GEM I saw, did something here
end

module Cool
  module Controller
    class CompanyController
    end
  end
  # The GEM I saw, did something here
end

module Cool
  module Controller
    class EmployeeController
    end
  end 
  # The GEM I saw, did something here
end
```

Comment: Just define a constant. 'Company = Model::Company'

Comment: And that will attach it (or at least make it available) on the module Cool namespace?

So that I can just do Cool::Company.new

Comment: If you define the constant on the global namespace, yes. To make sure you are doing this you can use `::Company = Model::Company`. The `::` prefix makes it refer to the root namespace

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces don't actually exist in Ruby. Ruby has module nesting - every module encapsulates its own constants. Classes are also modules.

When you use the `module` keyword Ruby actually does this:

```
ModuleName = Module.new do
  # ... 
end
```

You're linking an instance of Module to a constant. So if you want to "alias" `Cool::Model::Company` to `Company` you just define a constant in the `Company` module.

```
module Cool
  module Model
    class Company
    end
  end

  Company = Model::Company
end
```

But I'm failing to see why this is so cool with this since it will just cause havoc with the Rails autoloader as it will look in the autoloading roots for `cool/company.rb` and expect it to define the constant. Also whats the point of module nesting if your just going to alias it into the outer module and cause a potential naming collision anyways?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just so you know this is a Ruby question, not a Rails question, but I am assuming that the subfolders and subnamespaces would load correctly by the AutoLoader because they match (could be wrong). Also I'm looking for a generic alias where by every class in the model folder can loose it's child namespace at time of instantiation, not just one class at a time. I have seen this done in one of the popular GEM's, but I can't remember which

Comment: Then why is it tagged Rails?

Comment: My mistake, have removed the tag